# Get all child nodes of div using cheerio?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, cheerio

```
<div class="hello">
  Text1
  <li>Text2</li>
  <div class="bye">Text3</div>
  Text4 Block
  <div class="bye">Text5</div>
  Last Text5
</div>
```

So I have the above which I grab in cheerio using `$('div.hello')`.  I want to iterate through it.  How do I iterate through everything including the text nodes?  I tried using `$('div.hello').contents()` but this isn't grabbing the text nodes("Text1, "Text4 Block", and "Last Text5").  My end goal is to basically split the HTML block when I reach the first element that has a class of "bye".  So I want an array holding the following html strings,

```
final_array = ['Text1 <li>Text2</li>', '<div class="bye">Text3</div> Text4 Block <div class="bye">Text5</div> Last Text5']
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to use [map](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#map-functionindex-element-) or [filter](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#filter-selector---filter-selection---filter-element---filter-functionindex-) methods.

For example:

```
var text = $('div.hello').contents().map(function() {
    if (this.type === 'text')
        return $(this).text().trim()
}).get()
```

Basically in callback function you need to play with `if's` to get what you want.